# toFixed(); is only returning .00

Tags: javascript, jquery, tofixed

The below code is returning decimal places, but it's not returning values other than .00, when I have my values set to .67, 1.33, 2.67, etc.

```
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

**Here's where the js is pulling data from...**

```
            <legend>Transfer Course Information</legend>
<label for="School Int.">School Int.</label> 
          <input name="School Int." type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" /> &nbsp; 

          <label for="ID">ID</label>
          <input name="ID" type="text" id="ID" size="8" /> &nbsp; 

            <label for="Name">Name</label>
          <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="25" />&nbsp;

          <label for="Grade">Grade</label>
          <input name="Grade" type="text" id="Grade" size="2" />&nbsp; 

          <label for="Credits">Credits</label>
                <select name="Credits" id="Credits">
                    <option value="0">Select Credit</option>
                    <option value="0.67">1 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="1.33">2 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="2.00">3 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="2.67">4 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="3.33">5 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="4.00">6 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="4.67">7 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="5.33">8 QrtCr.</option>
                    <option value="6.00">9 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="6.67">10 QtrCr.</option>
                    <option value="1">1 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="2">2 SemCr. </option>
                    <option value="3">3 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="4">4 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="5">5 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="6">6 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="7">7 SemCr. </option>
                    <option value="8">8 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="9">9 SemCr.</option>
                    <option value="10">10 SemCr.</option>
                  </select>

          Transferrable
          <input name="COM105" type="checkbox" id="COM1" />
```

**I tried this, but it didn't work...**

```
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2).replace(".00", ""));
    });
});
```

Comment: So why are you using parseInt instead of parseFloat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `parseInt()`, which discards the fractions. Use `parseFloat()` instead.

```
$(function($) {
    $('#CourseMenu select').change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#CourseMenu select').each(function(idx, elm) {
            sum += parseFloat(elm.value);
        });

     $('#total_potential').html(Math.min(sum,72).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `parseInt` method parses strings into *integers* (whole numbers). One easy way to convert a string to number in JavaScript while maintaining the fractional part is using the unary plus operator:

```
sum += +elm.value;
```

The advantage/disadvantage of this compared to `parseFloat` is that it's stricter: if the string starts with numbers and is followed by letters, like `"123abc"`, this will return a NaN while `parseFloat` will return the number that could be parsed before the letters.

Comment: If you're going for short code, you could suggest `+elm.value`

Comment: Sure, the unary plus should work too, though I tend to use this "trick" instead of `parseFloat` mainly because of stricter parsing, not to make short code.

Comment: I wasn't sure of your intent :) So what are your `mainly for other reasons`? Just wondering. That and `+` have the same effect

Comment: Yeah I thought "other reasons" would be too vague and edited the comment :D

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah I definitely use `+` over `parseFloat` (always) for that reason :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "parseInt" on the values before your .toFixed() call, which will turn these floating points into ints. Try "parseFloat" instead and you should be all set.

Comment: I just figured that out. parseInt will only return .00. Thanks. In 11 minutes, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah you got it. parseInt() just drops everything after the decimal point, so if you're dealing with floating points you want to use parseFloat()